# Link_to edit in nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am confused on how nested resources should works and how can i access them
Here my model in question

```
event                      eventcomments
id                           id
Title                        body
Content                      event_id
...
```

Here my route file

```
resources :events do
  resources :eventcomments
  end
end
```

Here the relationship

```
Article
  has_many :eventcomments
Comments
  belongs_to event
```

But when i am in show.html.erb of events, I can't have the link to edit the comment. here the rake route produced

```
edit_event_eventcomment GET    /events/:event_id/eventcomments/:id/edit(.:format) eventcomments#edit
```

and my link to

```
<h2>Comments</h2>
<div>
<% @comments.each do |comment| %>
    <div>
      <%= image_tag (comment.customer.avatar).url(:thumb) %>
      <%= comment.customer.incomplete_name %> said: 
      <%= comment.description %>
      <div>Posted: <%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %></div>
      <% if current_customer.isadmin? %>
        <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_event_eventcomment_path(@event) %>
        <%= link_to 'Destroy', '#' %>
      <% end %>
    </div><br />
```

Here the error i am getting

```
NoMethodError in Eventcomments#edit

Showing /home/jean/rail/voyxe/app/views/eventcomments/_form.html.erb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `eventcomment_path' for #<#<Class:0xb5e73d84>:0xb5e7c8f8>
Extracted source (around line #1):

1: <%= form_for(@eventcomment) do |f| %>
2:   <% if @eventcomment.errors.any? %>
3:     <div id="error_explanation">
4:       <h2><%= pluralize(@eventcomment.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this eventcomment from being saved:</h2>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only passing an `Event` instance to the `edit_event_eventcomment_path` method and you should be passing the `Eventcomment` instance also.

Try with `edit_event_eventcomment_path(@event, comment)`

Note: Rename your `Eventcomment` class to `EventComment` or just `Comment`.

Comment: Where would i rename eventcomment? controller? model? views?

Comment: Your model should be named EventComment and not Eventcomment, it's just a naming convention. But if you ask me I'll name it just Comment.

Answer (score 1):

Your nested routes requires two parameters, :event_id and :id, like so:

```
edit_event_eventcomment_path(@event, comment)
```

Comment: Sure, this line of code is correct because it show the correct order in which ids are required by the params hash.